# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Error rises as a result of the find when i refresh the page it shows in a flash then the error cannot read property 'find' shows up. is there something i am not doing right?

`from my cartAction.js`
this what i am using to dispatch the action

```
xport const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
        product:data._id,
        name:data.name,
        image:data.image,
        price:data.price,
        countInStock:data.countInStock,
        qty
    }
})
localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
```

}

```
export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case CART_ADD_ITEM:
                const item = action.payload
                const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product)
    
                if (existItem) {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x =>
                            x.product === existItem.product ? item : x)
                    }
    
                } else {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item]
                    }
                }
    
            case CART_REMOVE_ITEM:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.filter(x => x.product !== action.payload)
                } 
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us where you're dispatching the action?

Comment: `const existItem= state.cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product)`

Comment: Please update the whole question with more infromation on what your action looks like and what you're dispatching within the action. Take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is my cartAction for dispatch...Export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product:data._id,
            name:data.name,
            image:data.image,
            price:data.price,
            countInStock:data.countInStock,
            qty
        }
    })
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}